# Problem with SQL syntax (probably simple)

Tags: sql, mysql, drupal

I'm doing some custom database work for a module for Drupal and I get the following SQL error when trying to create my table:

> user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL, `rooms` INT DEFAULT NULL, `adults` INT DEFAULT NULL, `children`' at line 14 query: CREATE TABLE dr_enquiry ( `eId` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `eKey` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `dateSent` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `status` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unanswered', `custName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, `custEmail` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, `custPhone` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, `custCountry` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, `custIP` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL, `offerName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `offerURL` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, `arrival` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, `departure` DEFAULT NULL, `rooms` INT DEFAULT NULL, `adults` INT DEFAULT NULL, `children` INT DEFAULT NULL, `childAges` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL, `toddlers` INT DEFAULT NULL, `toddlerAges` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL, `catering` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, `comments` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, `agent` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, `voucher` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (eId) ) /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 */ in /home/travelco/public_html/includes/database.inc on line 550.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'departure' field doesn't seem to have a type eg varchar, mediumint etc.  Try adding one and see if that solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Nullability is not set using a `DEFAULT` constraint. Thus, the compiler is balking at each instance of `DEFAULT NULL`. Thus, the create statement should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE dr_enquiry ( 
      eId INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
      , eKey VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
      , dateSent  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
      , status VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unanswered'
      , custName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
      , custEmail  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
      , custPhone VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
      , custCountry  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
      , custIP VARCHAR(11) NULL
      , offerName  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
      , offerURL VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
      , arrival  DATETIME NULL
      , departure DATETIME NULL
      , rooms  INT NULL
      , adults INT NULL
      , children  INT NULL
      , childAges VARCHAR(32) NULL
      , toddlers  INT NULL
      , toddlerAges VARCHAR(32) NULL
      , catering  VARCHAR(255) NULL
      , comments VARCHAR(255) NULL
      , agent VARCHAR(100) NULL
      , voucher  VARCHAR(100) NULL
      , PRIMARY KEY (eId) 
      )
```

(Oh and departure did not have a datatype as richsage mentioned. I presumed it was `DateTime`.)